# Updating record with Mongoid in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I am testing this from rails console:

```
Credential.last.token => nil
Credential.last.update_attribute :token, '123'   => true
Credential.last.token => nil
```

Here is my class:

```
class Credential
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :_id,              type: String
  field :user_id,          type: Integer
  field :code,             type: String
  field :provider,         type: String
  field :token,            type: String

end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to put

```
attr_accessor :token, ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have identity map enabled you'll need to wrap that in

```
Mongoid.unit_of_work { Credential.last.token }
```

Mongoid caches the queries. It is not a problem for web requests, but in the console you won't see the change unless you do it in the unit of work block, or restart the console (not just a reload)